# UpdateProgress and Loading bar

Tags: c#, asp.net, progress-bar, updatepanel, updateprogress

I used this tutorial in this link http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/10/how-to-show-progressbar-during.html to make the "Progress bar", it works well, but I have another UpdatePanel in the page, and every time I click a button in this UpdatePanel, the "progress bar" is displayed.

I don't want the progress bar to be displayed with every UpdatePanel in the page. I wrote `AssociatedUpdatePanelID="pnlData"` but still not works. How can I achieve this?

Another Question: if I have 2 buttons in the UpdatePanel  that associated with the UpdateProgress, and I want only one of theses buttons to show the progress bar not both of them, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the progress bar is shown for each button click and for each update panel is that the handler is bound to the page's request events:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
```

So with every AJAX roundtrip to the server the progress bar is first shown and then hidden.

To change this behavior I suggest to find out the originator of the request. I think it'll be available somewhere in the `sender` or `args` parameters of the `BeginRequestHandler`. Use F12 developer tools to debug the objects. Then just add an extra condition to the `popup.show();`. You can use this (or similar) approach to filter out the buttons and the update panels that should trigger the progress bar.

Usual approach is to show a progress bar only for long-running operations. So you'd wrap the `popup.show();` in [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) during the `BeginRequest` event and if the `EndRequest` is occurs earlier then specified timeout you'd reset the timeout using [`clearTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp).

Answer (score 0):

U mentioned that u have used AssociatedUpdatePanelID="pnlData". But, have you set the UpdateMode="Conditional". Like this:-

`<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">`

Comment: Yes I set it to "Conditional"